# How does the "locale" program work?

Tags: linux, locale

The `locale` program will print the locale variables of the process that launched it, this is a sample output of `locale` when launched from the shell:

```
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=
LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=
```

Where does `locale` get this information from (I know that this information is not `locale`'s inherited environment variables from the shell, because the shell only has 4 locale environment variables)?

Answer (score 3):

It gets it by knowing how locale settings are processed, based on the values of the corresponding environment variables.

Taking the GNU version as an example, it starts by [calling `setlocale (LC_ALL, "")`](https://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=blob;f=locale/programs/locale.c;h=86941e4ef6e67d78817f2ae0a10c919fb0ed0cb4;hb=HEAD#l220) to set the current locale. Then it goes through all [the locale categories](https://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=blob;f=locale/categories.def;h=56c5f88f6e1d0ae0f5d21550eb1b175348a52751;hb=HEAD), printing the value of each one in turn, with special exceptions for `LANG` (printed first) and `LC_ALL` (printed last). The values are determined by looking at the environment values and following the rules which apply to the locale settings:

- if `LC_ALL` is set, all categories take the corresponding value;
- if a category has no value set in the environment, it takes the value of `LANG` if it has one, “POSIX” otherwise and the value is enclosed in *double-quotes*.

Comment: So if a process have its current locale variables different from its locale variables in the environment variables, and the process launched the `locale` program, then the `locale` program will only output the locale variables in the environment variables, correct?

Comment: @James more or less. Locale settings aren’t inherited, yes, in particular because all processes run the equivalent of `setlocale(LC_ALL, "C")` when they start. The `locale` program will output the locales corresponding to whatever variables are present in the environment it was given (which is determined by the program which starts `locale`).

Answer (score 0):

The `locale` program prints it's results based on the environment variables.

The output you listed contains non-standard locales that may be Linux specific.

In order to understand how this works, it may be important to know:

- LC_ALL overwrites all other explicit LC_* variables in the environment.
- LANG is used as a fallback if a specific LC_XXX variable is not in the environment.