# What is the difference between LANG=C and LC_ALL=C?

Tags: locale

I like to disable all locale specific differences in shell scripts. What is the preferred way to do it?

`LANG=C` or `LC_ALL=C`

Answer (score 47, accepted):

`LANG` sets the default locale, *i.e.* the locale used when no more specific setting (`LC_COLLATE`, `LC_NUMERIC`, `LC_TIME` etc.) is provided; it doesn’t override any setting, it provides the base value. `LC_ALL` on the other hand overrides all locale settings.

Thus to override scripts’ settings, you should set `LC_ALL`.

You can check the effects of your settings by running `locale`. It shows the *calculated* values, in quotes, for all locale categories which aren’t explicitly set; in your example, `LANG` isn’t overriding `LC_NUMERIC`, it’s providing the default value. If `LC_ALL` and `LC_NUMERIC` aren’t set in the environment, the locale is taken from `LANG`, and `locale` shows that value for `LC_NUMERIC`, as indicated by the quotes.

See [the `locales` manpage](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/locale.7.html) and [the POSIX definitions of environment variables](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap08.html#tag_08_01) for details. See also [How does the "locale" program work?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/449318/86440)

Answer (score 12):

`LANG` does not override:

```
$ export LC_NUMERIC="de_DE.UTF-8"
$ export LANG=C
$ printf "%.2f\n" 3.14
-bash: printf: 3.14: invalid number
3,00
```

But `LC_ALL` does:

```
$ export LC_NUMERIC="de_DE.UTF-8"
$ export LC_ALL=C
$ printf "%.2f\n" 3.14
3.14
```