# How to force unzip listing to use unicode UTF-8

Tags: shell, zip, locale, unicode, macos

**ZIP**

```
zip -r --symlinks ../a.zip a a.txt 
  adding: a/šáčžřŠÁČÝŘŽÚ§/ (stored 0%)
```

Filename is stored properly in unicode.

**LIST**

```
unzip -l ../a.zip 
  Length      Date    Time    Name
---------  ---------- -----   ----
        0  03-11-2021 14:40   a/s??a??c??z??r??S??A??C??Y??R??Z??U??§/
```

unzip list prints crapy chars.

The filenames are stored in zip correctly in unicode because the unzip restores them properly but I need to show the zip listing in correct unicode chars.

How do I print the listing in correct unicode? Has this anything to do with shell settings?

**locale**

```
LANG=""
LC_COLLATE="C"
LC_CTYPE="UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="C"
LC_MONETARY="C"
LC_NUMERIC="C"
LC_TIME="C"
LC_ALL=
```

I'm on MacOS system.

Tried all this, still the same result :-(

```
LC_ALL=UTF-8 zip...
LC_ALL=UTF-8 unzip...

LANG =UTF-8 zip...
LANG =UTF-8 unzip...
```

I've also tried all lang variants:

```
LANG=cs_CZ.UTF-8 unzip -l ../unzip.zip
LANG=en_US.UTF-8 unzip -l ../unzip.zip
```

All these lang variants are listed in `locale -a` and still produce invalid output :-(

`bsdtar` works fine without any locale settings.

```
bsdtar tvvf ../unzip.zip 
drwxr-xr-x  0 501    20          0 Mar 11 14:40 a/šáčžřŠÁČÝŘŽÚ§/
Archive Format: ZIP 1.0 (uncompressed),  Compression: none
```

Comment: nope, still the same. Also tried export LANG=UTF-8 with same result ;-) Searching for the LC_ALL meaning now...

Comment: See [What is the difference between LANG=C and LC_ALL=C?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/576701/86440) for an explanation of `LANG` and `LC_ALL`. `LC_ALL=UTF-8 unzip ...` would override all the other `LC_` settings, unlike `LANG=UTF-8 unzip ...`.

Comment: Try `bsdtar tvvf file.zip` instead.

Answer (score 1):

It should work with

`LANG=en_US.UTF-8 unzip -l a.zip`

UTF-8 is not a valid value for LANG. To list available locales, try

`locale -a`

In case `en_US.UTF-8` is not listed there, try one of the ones that are listed and end in UTF-8.

I tried this on a Ubuntu system but I believe this should apply to Mac OS as well.
I also verified that I get similarly problematic outputs as you when setting `LANG=""` as is currently set in your locale or `LANG=UTF-8` as was suggested in the comments.

Comment: `LC_CTYPE=UTF-8` [is a thing in macos](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0538/#legacy-c-locale-coercion-in-the-standalone-python-interpreter-binary).

Comment: [How to generate C.UTF-8 locale in MacOS to use Postgresql](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/573886) suggests there's no `C.UTF-8` locale on macos.