# How to print UTF-8 symbols

Tags: bash, unicode

How can I print UTF-8 symbols on a terminal using bash commands.

This works

```
echo -e '\U2586'
```

But the following is failing

```
printf '%s\n' $(tput setaf 118) "\\u2586" $(tput sgr0)
```

Comment: You can also just type them, e.g. `printf "%s\n" ☺`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In bash, if you want `printf` to expand backslash escape sequences in arguments after the format string, you should [use `%b`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Builtins.html#index-printf) instead of `%s` in the format string:

```
printf '%b\n' "$(tput setaf 118)" "\u2586" "$(tput sgr0)"
```

Since you have three arguments, perhaps this might be more appropriate:

```
printf '%s%b%s\n' "$(tput setaf 118)" "\u2586" "$(tput sgr0)"
```

As [Stéphane Chazelas](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/22565/st%C3%A9phane-chazelas) pointed out, this will output the encoding of the U+2586 character in the current locale’s character set. If that’s UTF-8, the result will be UTF-8; other character sets will differ. If the character set can’t represent U+2586, the result will be the string “\u2586” (zsh will fail with a “character not in range” error instead).

This produces the behaviour you want in most cases: if possible, it displays “▆”. If you *really* want to output the UTF-8 representation of the character, in all cases, you can force that by overriding the locale, *e.g.*

```
LC_ALL= LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8 printf '%s%b%s\n' "$(tput setaf 118)" "\u2586" "$(tput sgr0)"
```

(See [What is the difference between LANG=C and LC_ALL=C?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/576701/86440) for an explanation of the variable settings used above.)

Comment: Technically bash (4.2 or above)'s `printf %b '\u2586'` will print the U+2586 (`▆`) character in the locale charset (0xe2 0x96 0x86 if it's UTF-8, 0xa8 0x7d if it's GB18030, etc) or as `\u2586` if the locale has no such character. For it to print it UTF-8 encoded regardless of the user's locale, you'd need `LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8 printf...` (or any other locale available on the system that uses UTF-8 as the charmap and assuming `$LC_ALL` is not otherwise set to a non-empty string).

Comment: Thanks @Stéphane, I’ve added that information to the answer. Do you know if it’s possible to disable the “character not in range” behaviour in zsh?

Comment: I don't think it is, though you can at least catch the exception using  the `always` keyword. This kind of issue is what is currently holding POSIX from finalising the specification of `$'...'`.

Answer (score 0):

Note that support for `\uxxxx` and `\UXXXXXXXX` was first added to the GNU implementation of the `printf` standalone utility in 2000, but like for other escape sequences, they are only recognised in the format argument or in arguments for `%b` specifiers. Not for `%s` which display the strings verbatim.

They were later added to the `printf` builtin of `zsh` in 2003 (and also for `echo`/`print` and `$'...'` there),  ksh93 in 2004, bash in 2010 (4.2) and probably a few more since.

That's not standard though. There is plan for [POSIX to specify the `$'...'` form of quotes from ksh93](https://www.austingroupbugs.net/view.php?id=249) and them to allow `\u`/`\U` sequences, but one of the blocking points at the moment is how to handle the expansion if the charset in the current locale was not UTF-8 at the time the command using those quotes was parsed and/or run.

Still, if your script was started in a locale where the charset is UTF-8 and you have not changed the locale (the `LC_CTYPE`, `LC_ALL` and `LANG` variables) since, using `$'\uxxxx'` is probably the most portable way to get the UTF-8 encoding of a character based on its Unicode codepoint.

Use `$'\UXXXXXXXX'` for characters with codepoint above 0xFFFF. Note that some shells do require all 4 digits for `\u` and all 8 digits for `\U`. So for maximum portability, use `$'St\u00E9phane'` or `$'St\U000000E9phane'` for `Stéphane` for instance. In any shell, you'll need `St\u00E9fan` for `Stéfan` as `$'St\ue9fan` would be treated as `St` `\U0E9F` `ane` since `f` is a hexadimal digit. With shells  that do support `$'\ue9'` you can also do `$'St\ue9'$'fan'` or `St$'\ue9'fan` and mix-and-match quote operators.

Then you can pass those expansions to any command, `printf` or otherwise.

In your particular case, you could use `zsh`'s `print` builtin as:

```
print -P '%F{118}\u2586%f'
```

Where `-P` enables prompt expansion where the foreground colour can be set without having to run the `tput` command. Or:

```
print -rP '%F{118}'$'\u2586''%f'
```

Where `-r` disables the escape sequences and pass the U+2586 character literally to `print` using the the `$'...'` form of quotes.

Or:

```
arbitrary_text=$'\u2586'' arbitrary text with \backslash and % characters'
print -r -- ${(%):-%F{118}}$arbitrary_text${(%):-%f}
```

Where `print` doesn't do any expansion, but the colour escape sequences are generated by the `%` parameter expansion flag, and the U+2586 stored verbatim in the variable.
print -r