# Why might `date` be showing 12h format?

Tags: date, locale

I've always seen 24h time shown in the `date` output. But for some reason, my Debian-based machine is now showing 12h time format:

```
$ date
Fri 10 Jun 2022 06:16:47 PM IDT

$ LC_TIME=en_IL.UTF-8 date
Fri 10 Jun 2022 06:17:00 PM IDT

$ LC_ALL=en_IL.UTF-8 date
Fri 10 Jun 2022 18:17:05 IDT
```

I don't think that I changed anything relevant lately.

```
$ grep LC_ ~/.bashrc
export LC_TIME="en_DK.UTF-8"
$ grep LC_ ~/.profile 
$ locale
LANG=en_IL.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=en_US
LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8
```

**What else should I check or configure?**

My goal would be to have **these features**:

- 24h time format
- YYYY-MM-DD date format
- Week starts on Sunday
- Text in English
- Beer served below room temp, but not at refrigerator levels of cold
- UTF-8 encoding

In **these applications**:

- Bash commands, such as `date`.
- Anki
- Firefox
- Thunderbird
- KeepassXC
- LibreOffice
- KDE Applications, such as Okular and Dolphin
- Gnome applications

My setup is KDE 5.18.8 on Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS. I have no problem updating to 22.04 if necessary.

Comment: @thanasisp: `file /etc/locale.conf ... No such file or directory`. Should I just create that file? I would prefer that all user-specific configs (which these are) would be done in the `/home/` directory. Not only because it is best practice, but also so that it will be backed up properly.

Comment: I think no, I am on different OS. I suggest you as a workaround to set `LC_TIME=POSIX` using the preferred Ubuntu method. Probably it is a bug after an update about locale `en_US*`.

Comment: Yeah, if you have a UK-type locale, the beer will be room temp. :)

Comment: @thanasisp: Setting `LC_TIME` in fact did not resolve the issue. I set it in `bashrc` and also tried setting it on the bash CLI when invoking `date`.

Comment: I have everything `en_US.utf8` except `LC_ALL=` empty and `LC_TIME=POSIX`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your times are shown in 12h format because of this setting:

```
LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8
```

This overrides your `LC_TIME` setting, and produces 12h times.

Presumably something changed recently to produce this `LC_ALL` setting in your environment. `grep -r LC_ALL /etc` should tell you where.

See also [What is the difference between LANG=C and LC_ALL=C?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/576701/86440) for context on `LANG` v. `LC_ALL`.

Comment: **Thank you!** On my work machine, with the same `~/.bashrc` and `~/.profile` files, in fact `LC_ALL` is not set. **And that work machine displays `date` output properly.** When I get home I'll grep around `/etc` on the affected machine.