# How do LC_ variables work?

Tags: locale

There are a lot of questions here about how to set these variables but none about how they work.

If I type `locale` in a terminal it shows me a bunch of variables:

```
LC_COLLATE="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="en_GB.UTF-8"
```

However, these don't exist on the system. Doing a echo returns blank string `echo $LC_MONETARY`.

I presume that the utility is reading some database and printing env vars that can be customized and set to override the defaults?

1. What is the database being read? Can it be edited directly without using these vars to override its settings?
2. If these vars are set, what system component uses them. Are these used by any user space programs?
3. Is `locale` part of a package that comes with other utilities?
4. Are the variables part of a standard and found on all distros?

Any reference to documentation that explains the LC_ vars and locale utility would be appreciated. Most web articles I found explain how to use these, but not the design/architecture of the locale system.

Comment: Have you read `man -k locale`?

Comment: @waltinator I have. It displays the various options and flags, i.e. the command usage, not the broader context.

Comment: If a `LC_*` envvar doesn't exists, `setlocale(LC_*, "")` guesses it from `LANG`, and `LC_ALL` overrides it.

Comment: The [locale(7)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/locale.7.html) and [setlocale(3)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/setlocale.3.html) manpages explain all that. tl;dr; you have either the `LANG=en_GB.UTF-8` or the `LC_ALL=en_GB.UTF-8` envvar set.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. The values aren’t read from a database. `locale` applies [precedence rules](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap08.html#tag_08_02): if `LANG` is set, it determines the default value for any unset `LC_` variable, and if `LC_ALL` is set, it overrides all values. For example, I have `LANG` and `LC_CTYPE` explicitly set to `en_GB.UTF-8`, and `locale` shows `en_GB.UTF-8` for all values; but if I set `LANG` to `fr_FR.UTF-8`, it shows `fr_FR.UTF-8` for all values *except* `LC_CTYPE`.
2. The variables are read by [the `setlocale` function](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/setlocale.html), which programs are supposed to call if they care about locales at all.
3. `locale` is usually part of the C library.
4. The variables are defined in [POSIX](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/), a standard which defines common interfaces found in most Unix-style systems. Some systems (or rather, C libraries) have extensions; for example [the GNU C library defines a number of non-standard locale categories](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/locale.7.html) such as `LC_ADDRESS`.

See also [What is the difference between LANG=C and LC_ALL=C?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/576701/86440) and [How does the "locale" program work?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/449318/86440)